# Ruby Marshal.load doesn't keep order of sorted set

Tags: ruby, marshalling, sortedset

I'm saving a SortedSet object in a file using Marshal.dump.
The elements in the set are objects as well (that include Comparable and implement the <=> method).

Later on when restoring that object using Marshal.load, the SortedSet that is loaded from the file is not sorted...

Any idea why or how to fix it?

Here is a simplified example that reproduce the problem:

```
require 'set'
class Foo
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :num

  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  def <=>(other)
    num <=> other.num
  end
end

f1 = Foo.new(1)
f2 = Foo.new(2)
f3 = Foo.new(3)

s = SortedSet.new([f2, f1, f3])

File.open('set_test.dump', 'wb') { |f| Marshal.dump(s, f) }
```

Than, to load the object from the file i use -

```
File.open('set_test.dump', 'rb') { |f| ls = Marshal.load(f) }
```

** I'm using Rails 3.2.3 with Ruby 2.1.8

** When loading the dump from the file - do it in a new/seperate rails console (and don't forget to copy-paste the definition of the Foo class :-) )

Comment: I tried this in Ruby 2.1.10 and 2.4.0. I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Nor do I see a problem. Note `File.open('set_test.dump', 'rb') { |f| ls = Marshal.load(f) }` can also be written `Marshal.load(File.binread('set_test.dump'))`.

Comment: Seriously? I just reproduced it in Ruby 2.1.10 and 2.2.2 (in IRB, no rails. Need to require 'set' )
Perhaps its related to the OS (I'm on Mac w/ OS-X El Capitan) ? or the fact I'm using RVM ? 
Weird that you cannot reproduce... I'm out of ideas... just shooting the breeze...

Comment: Mac Os X 10.9.5, Ruby 2.0.0, no RVM. I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Linux Mint, ruby 2.3.1p112, RVM. `Marshal.load` also returns `#<SortedSet: {#<Foo:0x0000000291b480 @num=2>, #<Foo:0x0000000291bbb0 @num=1>, #<Foo:0x00000002919d10 @num=3>}>`

Comment: @muistooshort : I don't understand your comment. Is a word missing?

Comment: I think he missed a 'not' - ... should **NOT** be using `Marshal`.
And he is right. When dumping using Marshal with a specific Ruby version, It might not load properly with a different Ruby version.

Comment: @EricDuminil Right, there is a missing *not* in there, I'll rewrite it.

Comment: As an aside, you really should not be using Marshal for persistence. The Marshal format is dependent (more or less) on the version of Ruby you're using and there's no guarantee that a newer/older Ruby will be able to read the older/newer formats. (As @ShaiKerer points out, there was a missing *not* in the original comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Reproducing the bug

I could reproduce this behaviour on every Ruby I tried.

```
# write_sorted_set.rb
require 'set'
class Foo
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :num

  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  def <=>(other)
    num <=> other.num
  end
end

f1 = Foo.new(1)
f2 = Foo.new(2)
f3 = Foo.new(3)

s = SortedSet.new([f2, f1, f3])
File.open('set_test.dump', 'wb') { |f| Marshal.dump(s, f) }
p s.to_a
```

and

```
# load_sorted_set.rb
require 'set'
class Foo
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :num

  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  def <=>(other)
    num <=> other.num
  end
end

ls = Marshal.load(File.binread('set_test.dump'))
p ls.to_a
```

When launching

```
ruby write_sorted_set.rb && ruby load_sorted_set.rb
```

It outputs

```
[#<Foo:0x000000010cae30 @num=1>, #<Foo:0x000000010cae08 @num=2>, #<Foo:0x000000010cadb8 @num=3>]
[#<Foo:0x0000000089be08 @num=2>, #<Foo:0x0000000089bd18 @num=1>, #<Foo:0x0000000089bc78 @num=3>]
```

## Why?

#### Comparable isn't used

Using this definition :

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :num
  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end
end
```

in `load_sorted_set.rb` should raise an exception (`comparison of Foo with Foo failed (ArgumentError)`), but it doesn't. It looks like `SortedSet` isn't properly initialized by `Marshal.load`

#### lib/set.rb

Looking at the [sourcecode](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/set.rb#L628) for `SortedSet` :

```
  module_eval {
    # a hack to shut up warning
    alias old_init initialize
  }
```

and

```
      module_eval {
        # a hack to shut up warning
        remove_method :old_init
      }

      @@setup = true
    end
  end

  def initialize(*args, &block) # :nodoc:
    SortedSet.setup
    initialize(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

It looks like `SortedSet` has been patched to ensure that `SortedSet.setup`
 is executed before any `SortedSet` is initialized.

`Marshal.load` doesn't seem to know about this.

## Solution

#### SortedSet.setup

You can call

```
SortedSet.setup
```

after `require 'set'` and before `Marshal.load`

#### SortedSet.new

You can force a `SortedSet` initialization with :

```
ls = SortedSet.new(Marshal.load(File.binread('set_test.dump')))
```

Comment: Nice findings! although I'm not sure I understand how that hack in the sourcecode explains the problem...

Also, in the "real world" my problem is more complicated than that, and its a part of objects hierarchy, so your suggested solution is not possible...
Perhaps I'll override the 'load' method in my class as a patch.

I was hoping there is a valid solution, without hacks or patches.
Perhaps there is a way to monkey patch SortedSet ?
Thanks!

Comment: Cool. It's always fun to look at Ruby source code and try to understand some bits.